# Is it possible to rotate the TTY1 console screen without X support?

Tags: xorg, display, tty

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS booting directly to tty1. The machine is an Intel NUC with a Core i5 + iGPU, display connected through Display Port. As far as I can tell, it does not have any graphical interface. No X, so no xrandr.

I want to rotate the TTY1 console screen by 90 degrees CCW, is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68369/rotate-console-on-startup-debian or https://www.happyassassin.net/2011/06/28/tip-o-the-day-console-rotation/